# Matlab: speed up large for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization, nested-loops

I'm trying to get 3 by 3 masks from a large matrix into vectors.  Currently, this is my code:

```
A=rand(3264,2448)

[rows cols]=size(A);

T=zeros(9,prod(size(A)-2));

for i=1:rows-2

  for j=1:cols-2

    T(:,(i-1)*cols+j)=reshape(A(i:i+2,j:j+2),[9 1]);

  end

end
```

Currently, this takes a rather long time.  Can I speed it up in any way?   I'm thinking meshgrid and arrayfun, but can't quite get my head around them.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing that `A` is not random values in the actual case? And does it matter in what order you extract the masks (kernels) from the large matrix? Currently it appears that you're going across the columns first and then incrementing the rows. One simple speedup is to not call `reshape` and instead do this: `Ai = A(i:i+2,j:j+2); T(:,(i-1)*cols+j)=Ai(:);`. That's about 50% faster on my machine.

Comment: A is image data in the actual case.  The order is irrelevant, as we're going to see each of those masks as a point in 9-D space.

Comment: The following is about 30% faster:

j=1;
for i=1:prod(size(A))-2*rows-2
    testrow=mod(i,rows);
    if (testrow~=rows-1 & testrow~=rows-2)
        T(:,j)=A([i;i+1;i+2;i+rows;i+rows+1;i+rows+2;i+2*rows;i+2*rows+1;i+2*rows+2]);
    end
end

Comment: Try `im2col` ...

Comment: @natan Of course....this is Matlab, where there's a frickin' function for _everything_!  Thank you!

Comment: @natan that takes around a second, whereas my faster code takes 140 seconds.  Nice.

Comment: +1 for `im2col`. By the way, I believe you have a bug in your `for` loops that is slowing them down slightly. You're reallocation memory. The output dimensions of `T` are not the same as those you specify via `zeros`. Either `T` needs to be allocated differently or you need `T(:,(i-1)*(cols-2)+j)=...`. Constantly growing an array is a surefire way to slow things down.

Comment: [Hankel matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) to rearrange image blocks into columns, for example:

```
T =  im2col(A,[3 3],'sliding');
```